# Office JavaScript API: highlighting text in a document

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, office365-apps

I'm working on a side project using the Microsoft Office JavaScript APIs. I have been relying on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office) to find my way around, but I've hit a wall trying to find something in the docs (perhaps it isn't there because it doesn't exist).

Recently I attempting to implement some functionality to highlight some text within a Word document. I don't want to *modify* the document, mind you; in other words I would rather not use something like [ContentControl.insertHtml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=office-js#inserthtml-html--insertlocation-) as that would change the actual content. What I want is to make the text *temporarily* highlighted (e.g., until the user clicks a "Cancel" button), much like what you see when you perform a search with Ctrl+F (and text matching your search is highlighted in yellow).

Is this possible using the Office JavaScript APIs?

Answer (score 2):

Try getting a reference to the Range object and then setting [Range.font.highlightcolor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=office-js#highlightcolor). Have a handler for the Cancel button click event that reverses the color change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample application that uses font.highlightcolor from the Office Javascript API. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JS-Redact/