# How can I format text without changing document state in MSWord web add-in API?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I'm developing an add-in for MSWord using Microsoft web add-in API. I'd like to underline or highlight some given words, but only in the scope of that session. I don't want to change the document's state. In other words, I don't want to persist the new text formatting when the document is saved.

I know how to format text, but the document's state is changed. I have this code at the moment:

```
word_range.font.underline = Word.UnderlineType.wave;
```

I want to achieve a behavior similar to Grammarly plug-in, where the underline is only to point out something is wrong with those words, but again, without persisting the underlining.

I found a similar question ([word - highlight search results without permanently changing document formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40028375/6145656)), but it was asked a few years ago and the solution is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no way to highlight that will automatically disappear if the user saves the document. The answer that you linked to, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248561/office-javascript-api-highlighting-text-in-a-document) is the best that can be done in Office.js right now. It is a good idea, however, so please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I understand. But how do they do this in Grammarly add-in? They underline text in a custom manner, it's not the same underline as you would do manually with the mouse, and it doesn't affect the document content itself.

Comment: Grammerly for Office seems to have its own installer. That means its not an Office Web Add-in using Office.js.